# Can I use MailCore with oauth 2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, mailcore

I've build a simple project that connects to gmail with OAuth 2.0. How can I use MailCore to fetch emails using the token I got from gmail? I've read the documentation of MailCore but couldn't find anything related.
Thanks

Comment: As of the time of this post, neither MailCore or MailCore2 support XOAuth2 over SASL yet.  I know MC2 has plans to get it into the framework.

Comment: I'm also following this closely and hoping that MC2 will implement it soon.

Comment: Huzzah, MailCore2 just got Xoauth2 support.  Now can we close this as off topic?